# Obtaining full cookie list from WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to get the full list of cookies stored after a request in a C# WebBrowser control. The code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class ExtractHttpOnlyCookie
    {
        [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool InternetGetCookieEx(string pchURL, string pchCookieName, StringBuilder pchCookieData, ref uint pcchCookieData, int dwFlags, IntPtr lpReserved);
        const int INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = 0x00002000;

        public static string GetGlobalCookies(string url)
        {
            uint datasize = 100000;
            StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder((int)datasize);

            if (InternetGetCookieEx(url, null, data, ref datasize, INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY, IntPtr.Zero) && data.Length > 0)
                return data.ToString();
            else
                return null;
        }

    }
}
```

This doesn't work. There are many cookies missing when compared to the output from Fiddler. Is there some other way? I checked every property and method on the WebBrowser but there's nothing useful. Any info you provide would be appreciated. Thanks.

**Addendum**

I've considered that JS on the page might be adding more cookies after page load. It's fairly complicated script so I've not analysed it yet. But I injected a function to run document.cookie and the output was the same as what wininet.dll returned. So this might not be the case? Page content and cookie data could be provided if it helps.

Comment: [FindFirstUrlCacheEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-findfirsturlcacheentryw). You're supposed to get  `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 0x7A` for each entry in the list, because the function will return the correct buffer size in `lpcbCacheEntryInfo` (the buffer is variable in size, depending on the type of `lpszUrlSearchPattern` and the size of each entry). This goes on calling [FindNextUrlCacheEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-findnexturlcacheentryw) after, until you get  `ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 0x103`.

Comment: It's important that you call [FindCloseUrlCache](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-findcloseurlcache) when the enumeration terminates. The entries in the enumeration can be filtered using a specific URL. -- To declare the FILETIME menbers of [INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/ns-wininet-internet_cache_entry_infow), you can use the [FILETIME](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/ns-wininet-internet_cache_entry_infow) structure provided by `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes`.

Comment: This is great Jimi! Thanks, you saved me a lot of time. I'll post the code as a reference. Just for interest, ```IntPtr handle = FindFirstUrlCacheEntry("cookie:", bufferHandle, ref bufferSize);``` returns everything from the cache, not just cookies.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You have a couple of flaws in the procedure you have posted (and one that can be fatal: `Marshal.ReAllocHGlobal()`). You need a `while (true)` loop and continue while `GetLastWin32Error() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)`. Each iteration re-initialize the buffer length to `0` and `bufferHandle` to `IntPtr.Zero`. Use this form to marshal: `Marshal.PtrToStructure<INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO>(bufferHandle)`. Every iteration: `if (bufferHandle != IntPtr.Zero) Marshal.FreeHGlobal(bufferHandle);` Anyway, I can post the whole procedure, if you want.

Comment: Thanks but nevermind, I ended up using CefSharp because WebBrowser is such a pain in the ass and doesn't run scripts correctly. Not to mention the pInvoke nightmare. Thanks anyway..

Comment: Yes, well, it's an old warrior. It needs some rest :) There's WebView2, anyway (all right, still not fully implementing Chrome in .Net, but it's already pretty good).

Answer (score -1):

Based on the suggestions from @Jimi here is some code to get the cache information. Note that it gets everything, and the list must be filtered if you want cookies or cache entries from a specific site.

```
public class ExtractHttpOnlyCookie
{
    [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool InternetGetCookieEx(string pchURL, string pchCookieName, StringBuilder pchCookieData, ref uint pcchCookieData, int dwFlags, IntPtr lpReserved);

    [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool InternetGetCookie(string url, string cookieName, StringBuilder cookieData, ref int size);

    [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, EntryPoint = "FindFirstUrlCacheEntryA", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindFirstUrlCacheEntry([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string lpszUrlSearchPattern, IntPtr lpFirstCacheEntryInfo, ref int lpdwFirstCacheEntryInfoBufferSize);

    [DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool FindNextUrlCacheEntry(IntPtr hEnumHandle, IntPtr lpNextCacheEntryInfo, ref int lpdwNextCacheEntryInfoBufferSize);

    [DllImport("wininet.dll")]
    public static extern bool FindCloseUrlCache(IntPtr hEnumHandle);

    const int INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = 0x00002000;
    const int INTERNET_COOKIE_THIRD_PARTY = 0x10;
    const int INTERNET_FLAG_RESTRICTED_ZONE = 0x00020000;
    const int ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER = 0x7A;
    const int ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS = 0x103;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO
    {
        public int dwStructSize;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] public String lpszSourceUrlName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] public String lpszLocalFileName;
        public int CacheEntryType;
        public int dwUseCount;
        public int dwHitRate;
        public int dwSizeLow;
        public int dwSizeHigh;
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME LastModifiedTime;
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME ExpireTime;
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME LastAccessTime;
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME LastSyncTime;
        public IntPtr lpHeaderInfo;
        public int dwHeaderInfoSize;
        public IntPtr lpszFileExtension;
        public int dwExemptDelta;
    }

    public static string GetGlobalCookies(string url)
    {
        //uint datasize = 100000;
        //StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder((int)datasize);

        //if (InternetGetCookieEx(url, null, data, ref datasize, INTERNET_COOKIE_HTTPONLY, IntPtr.Zero) && data.Length > 0)
        //    return data.ToString();
        //else
        //    return null;

        int bufferSize = 0;
        FindFirstUrlCacheEntry("cookie:", IntPtr.Zero, ref bufferSize);
        int lastBufferSize = bufferSize;
        IntPtr bufferHandle = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(lastBufferSize);
        IntPtr handle = FindFirstUrlCacheEntry("cookie:", bufferHandle, ref bufferSize);
        bool continueFlag = true;
        List<INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO> cacheItemList = new List<INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO>();
        INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO cacheItem;
        Type itemType = typeof(INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO);

        while (continueFlag)
        {
            cacheItem = (INTERNET_CACHE_ENTRY_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(bufferHandle, itemType);
            cacheItemList.Add(cacheItem);

            bufferSize = lastBufferSize;
            continueFlag = FindNextUrlCacheEntry(handle, bufferHandle, ref bufferSize);

            if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS)
                break;

            if (bufferSize > lastBufferSize)
            {
                lastBufferSize = bufferSize;
                bufferHandle = Marshal.ReAllocHGlobal(bufferHandle, (IntPtr)lastBufferSize);
                continueFlag = true;
            }
        }

        FindCloseUrlCache(handle);
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(bufferHandle);

        return "";//put output here
    }

}
```